# What is the simple subject in "Is that my bike"?

Tags: subjects, subject-verb-inversion

> Is that my bike?

I'm not sure if the simple subject is *that* or *bike*.

Comment: In this specific case, *that* would be the subject. In 'Is that **a** bike?', there is ambiguity -- either *that* or *bike* could be the subject, depending on what is intended.

Comment: @Kris, no, that isn't quite correct. The article plays no part in determining the subject in your example. You would differentiate between a specific or general bike, but the subject is always 'that'. "That is a bike." "Is that a bike?" For example. Maybe you could clarify?

Comment: @Adam cf. Bill Franke below.

Answer (score 6):

The grammatical subject is the demonstrative pronoun *that*: *That is my bike*. To turn the statement into a *Yes–No* question, subject–verb inversion is the usual rule: ⇒ *Is that my bike?* But *That is my bike?* with a rising tone is also a *Yes–No* question.

*That* comes before the verb and is the subject of *is*.

The logical subject is *bike* because that's what the sentence is about: the bike.

*That* is a pronoun that replaces *bike* in this sentence.

Comment: It looks to me like "is" operates symmetrically here, just stating that the two sides are equal. "That is my bike" is the same, with each word playing precisely the same grammatical role, as "My bike is that".

Comment: They can't play the same grammatical role. One has to be the grammatical subject and the other the subject complement. Change the positions of _that_ and _my bike_ and the sentence you get should become _My bike is that one_. Semantically they're the same, yes. A simpler example: _John is my brother_ = _My brother is John_. Same meaning but different grammatical subjects and different focus and they answer two different questions: _Who is John?_ and _Who is your brother?_.

Comment: Either answer can be given to either question. They *do* play the same grammatical role even if you think they can't. Here, "is" functions like an equal sign, stating that the two subjects are equivalent. Which one you choose to call the "grammatical subject" is arbitrary. "Who is your brother?" is equally well answered by "*John* is my brother" as it is by "My brother is *John*".

Comment: @david: You'll have to document that claim. It's like saying two different 3D bodies can simultaneously occupy the same space. I know theoretical physics makes strange claims; I'm not aware of that one. Do you also claim that _John, my brother, is the policeman_ has three simultaneous grammatical subjects even though linguists might label the 1st a _grammatical subject_, the 2nd a _noun in apposition_, & the 3rd a _subject complement_? While any one **can** be the grammatical subject, position seems to determine which one is which. Why else different names but for different functions?

Comment: @david: Perhaps "equally well answered" in speech, but formally, _John is my brother_ is the correct answer. Does "End with" = "With end"?

Comment: No. In "John, my brother, is the policeman", "is" also functions as a symmetric, but "my brother" serves as a qualifier. It's precisely the same as "The policeman is John, my brother" with every word having precisely the same grammatical role, only the order changes. (And it's bizarre to argue that a word order change, with no meaning change, fundamentally changes the roles the words play.)

Comment: @David: Documentation, David? Am I supposed to take your word for it? I will take John Lawler's word for it because I'm absolutely certain that he knows what he's talking about: He's a professional linguist and I know his work. He's one of the authorities on English grammar. I haven't seen your work, and I don't take the word of all professional linguists, viz., Huddleston and Pullum, authors of the _CGEL_. Some people have clout; others don't. Does "End with" = "With end"?

Comment: I don't understand your "end with" "with end" question. There certainly might be contexts where the two words play precisely the same grammatical role regardless of order and also contexts where they don't. What difference, other than word order, do you see between "The policeman is John, my brother" and "John, my brother, is the policeman"? In both cases, "is" indicates that "the policeman" and "John" are the same entity. (Again, it's bizarre to argue that a word order change, with no meaning change, fundamentally alters the roles the words play.)

Answer (score 0):

It should be *that*. Let's consider the following example:

> That is his bike.

Now if you remove *that*, the setence becomes:

> *is his bike. *And you are left wondering what bike is his*

Comment: “*And you are left wondering who the bike belongs to*” is wrong or irrelevant:  the bike is “his” for both of your example seNtences.

Comment: @jwpat7: you are right. Fixed it.