# What is the subject in the following sentence? This is the book I wanted

Tags: subjects, predicate

> This is the book I wanted.

In this sentence, is 'this' the formal subject and 'book' the real Subject?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the simple subject in "Is that my bike"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84306/what-is-the-simple-subject-in-is-that-my-bike). The sentence 'That is his bike' is also parsed.

Answer (score 1):

"this" is the subject, "the book I wanted" is the subject complement. "book" is merely a noun within the phrase that constitutes the complement.

If you invert the sentence to

> The book I wanted is this one.

then "The book I wanted" becomes the subject.

They both have very similar meanings, but the emphasis is different.